# How can I add silent audio channel/AAC codec to an MP4 file for Safari?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mp4, mediarecorder

Wondering if anyone can help me out here!

I'm currently saving a HTML5 Canvas as an MP4 file via the MediaRecorder API. Now my canvas doesn't contain any audio but I need an audio channel built in as the file with just h.264 and no audio codec isn't compatible with a piece of software I am using.

Is there anyway to force Safari to bake in an audio codec into the stream even though there is no audio being used in the canvas?

Essentially I'm trying to achieve the following: AAC, H.264

Rather than what I have right now: H.264

Here is what I have so far (minus some other details):

```
  // setup media recording
  const recordedChunks = [];
  const stream = canvas.captureStream(60);

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => recordedChunks.push(e.data);
  mediaRecorder.onstop = async (e) => {
    const download = (fileName, url) => {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = "display: none";

      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();

      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

    // download video
    const videoData = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/mp4" });
    download("1.mp4", URL.createObjectURL(videoData));

  }

  // start recording
  mediaRecorder.start();

  // do some canvas related operations
  // ...

  mediaRecorder.stop();
```

I guess if there's no work around here I might just resort to adding a silent audio channel to the video via FFMPEG.

**UPDATE:
The accepted answer didn't actually work for me so I resorted to adding the audio channel through FFMPEG which worked. Accepted anyway as it does add an audio channel to the outputted file.**

Thank you!

Comment: If you put most interest part of code maybe someone will help you. Is your app full frontend without node.js running services ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic sorry mate! Added a snippet to the post and this is purely JS/HTML, thank you.

Comment: I tested this code in local works fine.  I just added setTimeout with 10 sec for example and i got ` a.click();` works fine also. Video playing well on windows10 default player.

Comment: @NikolaLukic appreciate your time on this! The problem is I need an audio channel for using these videos in another piece of software. If an audio channel isn't present inside the video container it won't recognise the video. So I'm trying to add an audio channel to the file. I may close this question as it's quite complex in nature. The videos play fine in most video players and browsers. It's just some players require an audio channel to be built in to recognise the file as a valid mp4. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: No problem i will try it now , it is interest also for me !

Comment: @NikolaLukic this may interest you! I'm going to just re-encode the mp4 file and add a silent audio channel into it so it will be recognised by some software providers who have problems with video only mp4 files.

https://support.learnyst.com/en/articles/2793974-how-to-add-silent-audio-track-to-videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with codecs and such but you can add a silent audio channel to a video stream as follows:

```js
const stream = canvas.captureStream(60);

const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.frequency.value = 0;
const streamAudioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
oscillator.connect(streamAudioDestination);
oscillator.start();

// add audio track
const audioStream = streamAudioDestination.stream;
const audioTracks = audioStream.getAudioTracks();
const firstAudioTrack = audioTracks[0];
stream.addTrack(firstAudioTrack);

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

---

Note that initialization of AudioContext should happen in response to a user action (e.g. within a click handler). Thank you @[Nikola Lukic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513187/nikola-lukic) for noticing this!

Comment: Oh mate this is exactly what I needed! Sorry I'm not super familiar with Audio tracks and the MediaRecorder Audio APIs. You just saved my day! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have `The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.  Maybe i need to put it intro func then on first click call it.

Comment: @NikolaLukic thank you, that's a good point! Indeed, AudioContext initialization should happen in response to a user action.

Comment: Quick update! Though this answer does add an audio channel it didn't resolve my issue. Adding an audio channel via FFMPEG resolved my issue. Accepting this answer anyway as it does technical add an audio channel to the file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody have `The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.`

Here is adapted example used @ziz Yokubjonov code:

```js
function LOAD() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  // setup media recording
  const recordedChunks = [];
  const stream = canvas.captureStream(60);

  // let combined = new MediaStream([...videoStream.getTracks(), ...audioStream.getTracks()]);
  let options = {
    audio: true,
    audioBitsPerSecond: 64000,
  };

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = 0;
  const streamAudioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
  oscillator.connect(streamAudioDestination);
  oscillator.start();

  // add audio track
  const audioStream = streamAudioDestination.stream;
  const audioTracks = audioStream.getAudioTracks();
  const firstAudioTrack = audioTracks[0];
  stream.addTrack(firstAudioTrack);

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => recordedChunks.push(e.data);
  mediaRecorder.onstop = async (e) => {
    const download = (fileName, url) => {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = "display: block";
      a.innerHTML = 'LINK';
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();

      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

    // download video
    const videoData = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/mp4"});
    download("1.mp4", URL.createObjectURL(videoData));

  }

  // start recording
  mediaRecorder.start();

  // do some canvas related operations
  var x = 10
  setInterval(function() {
    x += 20
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
    ctx.fillText("TEST TEST", x, 50, 200, 50);
  }, 1000)
  ctx.fillText("TEST TEST", 10, 50, 200, 50);

  setTimeout(function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }, 10000)

}

function attachFunction() {
  LOAD();
  window.removeEventListener("click", attachFunction)
}

window.addEventListener("click", attachFunction)
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for following up mate!

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks, maybe this will help?

````
    ```a.href``` = 
    url:
````

---

`````
    ````a.download``` = 
    fileName:
`````

---

````
    ```a.click```(.264):
    ():
    ```c.AAC```
````

---

````
    ```H.264```
````

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for submitting your answer, is this javascript? The syntax looks unfamiliar...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).